# Ansible: Remove whitespaces in json file

Tags: json, ansible, jinja2

I have a json file content loaded in my ansible variables.

The json content (and the resulting file I write from it) has unnecessary file spaces and blank lines. I want to minify the json file by removing all that unnecessary stuff.

Is it possible to do something like `{{ myjson_content| to_json_minify }}` ?

Maybe this can be done through a regex ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read it from json and convert back into json with `separators` option.

```yaml
{{ my_json_content | from_json | to_json(separators=(',',':')) }}
```

*Note: this is not documented, but if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/36519ff95eddea72d7c16f9a7c3e8501ee0ab60e/lib/ansible/plugins/filter/core.py#L66) you will see that the filter accepts arbitrary keywords args which are later passed to the python [`json.dumps` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps). So you can basically pass to `to_json` any parameter accepted by `json.dumps`.*

**`playbook.yml`**

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
      my_json_content:
        '
          { "a" :   0,

          "b":   1,

            "c":    2}

        '
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "json = {{ my_json_content }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "minified_json = {{ my_json_content | from_json | to_json(separators=(',',':')) }}"
```

**`$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml`**

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "json =  { \"a\" :   0,\n\"b\":   1,\n\"c\":    2}\n"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "minified_json = {\"a\":0,\"c\":2,\"b\":1}"
}
```